# How should i call custom workflow rules

Tags: apex, workflow

There is some requirement therefore we are thinking to create custom workflows. There would be some additional tasks and operations but workflow invocation would be same as workflow rules.

We will be create workflow on some object and there would be some entry criteria. Workflow would get fired on object record creation or modification. Everything is fine as concerned with workflow rule, criteria and tasks.

> My question is how would i call that custom workflow when user create
>   or modify records? One solution that comes in my mind is write a
>   trigger on every object manually on which we are creating workflows.
>   Is there any other better approach?

Comment: for work flow you can select Evaluate the rule when a record is: created, and every time it’s edited,if you want it to be fired every time record is created or updated.

Comment: @snehakem Its not salesforce workflow that will get fired automatically. That is custom workflow so i will have to write some code to trigger that and that is my question.

Answer (score 2):

No there is no other option, You have to write trigger on each object for which the custom workflows are created. Say After Insert, After Update which will take care of both situations **On Create** and **On Modify**.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the *Evaluation Criteria* of your workflow to *"Created, and every time it’s edited"*. In this case your workflow will run when you create an object(record) and every time you edit it. For some basic workflow training you can check [its' *Trailhead* page](https://developer.salesforce.com/en/trailhead/business_process_automation/workflow).

Comment: Its not salesforce workflow that will get fired automatically. That is custom workflow so i will have to write some code to trigger that and that is my question.